# Show this is complex differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove or disprove $f$ defined on a complex neighborhood of $0$, $$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}} &\text{ if } x\not= 0\\0 &\text{ if } x=0.\end{cases}$$
is complex differentiable. I haven't learned complex variables, so I'm writing this function as one from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$. Is there any direct way showing it's complex differentiable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ajotatxe wrote: The function $f$ is complex differentiable for all $x\neq 0$. Now you have $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0, x\neq 0}f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0, x\neq 0} \frac x{x+1} = 0 = f(0)$$ Thus $f$ is continuous in $x=0$. Now [Riemann's theorem about removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem) states, that $f$ must be also complex differentiable at $x=0$.

Note: Differentiability of function $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ is not the same as complex differentiability. The later one is stronger.

Answer (score 0):

For $x\neq0$, this is the same as $$\frac x{x+1}$$
which is complex differentiable.

Comment: What about $x=0$?